# JW Player encoding files in folder

Tags: javascript, php, jwplayer

I got the code for self hosting JW player from the JW player's Website. i working in PHP

```
              <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

          <script type="text/javascript">
     jwplayer("myElement").setup({

    file: "PHP cURL Tutorial Part 1- Basic Structure.mp4",
    });
      </script>
```

Above code only encodes one video, but my website allows Multiple users to upload videos to my server.
My question is how can i encode all those files which are uploded in the folder on my ftp. 
Or
how can i use variable instead of **file: "PHP cURL Tutorial Part 1- Basic Structure.mp4",** so every video can be played.

path to my folder will be like this
http://www.mywebsite.com/jwplayer/videos/

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach would be to configure your JW Player to point to an RSS playlist file:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    ...
    "playlist": "http://www.mywebsite.com/jwplayer/playlist.rss",
    ...
});
```

And then write a PHP script to generate the "playlist.rss" dynamically based on the contents of the directory.

```
$video_dir = "videos";
$video_files = scandir($video_dir);

echo '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="http://rss.jwpcdn.com/">';
echo '<channel>';

foreach($video_files as $file) {
    if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
        echo '<item>';
        echo '<title>Title</title>';
        echo '<description>Description</description>';
        echo '<jwplayer:image>URL to image</jwplayer:image>';
        echo '<jwplayer:source file="http://www.mywebsite.com/jwplayer/videos/'.$file.'" />';
        echo '</item>';
    }
}

echo '</channel>';
echo '</rss>';
```

Check out the following for more information on configuring JW Player with RSS playlists - https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1406722-rss-playlist-embed

Comment: That's not very helpful... Do you have a link to an example page where you've tried to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (pseudo code).  Essentially an alternative to doing an RSS file, instead just iterate the files you've scanned from the directory to write out the JS:

```
    playlist: [        
      foreach($video_files as $file) {
        echo '{';
        echo 'title: {title},';
        echo 'description: {description},';
        echo 'file: $file,';
        echo '}';
      }
    ]
```